# Gmail blocking pixel tracking / 1x1 pixel since today morning

Tags: email, gmail, tracking

I was implementing pixel tracking for a gmail web service, but since today google has changed the gmail client to proxy linked images !

[image: link to my screen-capture]

Is there any work around, as the proxy is giving my server a fake/masked ip and location?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is true. gmail has been proxying all user content via it thus showing **Mountain View,CA** as its **REMOTE_ADDR**. This is true only for gmail clients. The same logic has not been working on Gmail via outlook or any other mail client. 
Most email tracking companies rely on these details to differentiate the recepients of the mail. 
I dont think there is a work around. But if there is one we would find out soon given that these companies have a lot to lose.

Meanwhile, you could try using **HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR** or **disposition notification headers**. But given that this can be messed with, there isnt much option left but just go back to making people click on links!!!

Comment: I already tried "forwarded for" but it returns null, is there no other workaround?

Answer (score 2):

In my experience as of Aug 5 2018 my emails sent with a tracking pixel are blocked by google. I uncheck the send tracking pixel box in my crm and the message arrives instantly.  The tracked email never arrives.

I made a video to show but its exactly as I just described and quite boring to watch lol. BUt you get the point.  Obviously this is just in my experience but it's too bad because knowing if my clients read it is only way know not to keep sending the same message in a different way assuming it went to spam.

Comment: Was the tracking image the only image in the email? My guess would be that it was simply the presence of the image (any image) that caused the issue. After all, Gmail has to load the image before it can determine that it is a 1x1 gif.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like they're caching, not just proxying.. I whipped up a PHP file to output a random image selected out of a collection of 5 images... It's the same image each time.. Testing against Yahoo! mail and outlook, both of which change each time the email is opened..

Comment: http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2013/12/images-now-showing.html

In Gmail's announcement, they said image caching allows them to securely turn on images by default.