# Gmail Cache messing up pixel tracking

Tags: php, email, gmail, tracking

I can´t seem to bypass gmail image caching to correctly track when an email is opened.

The script works properly, the only problem is that when google downloads the image to save it in its cache it´s triggering the script that makes it seem like it was opened. 
I already tried adding:

```
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

but it wont do any difference. Any ideas how to bypass this?

I already found this answer with an explanation, but fails to provide any solution: [Gmail blocking pixel tracking / 1x1 pixel since today morning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20379732/gmail-blocking-pixel-tracking-1x1-pixel-since-today-morning)

Comment: Because they don't want you doing that because it's shady af.

Comment: Doesn´t every email marketing company do it? How do they do it?

Comment: gmail only caches it on the first open, so measuring that still works as usual. But you will lose the ability to tell if its opened again.