# How to track emails in gmail with PHP

Tags: php, html-email

Hi I built an email tracker and it works fine except on Gmail

IMG CODE on HTML email sent

```html
$track_code = md5(rand());
<img src="https://www.syste-mart.com/tracker.php?code='.$track_code.'" width="1" height="1" title="Syste-mart">
```

tracker.php

```html
<?php
include "conexion.php";
$db = mysql_connect($host,$username,$passwordDB);
mysql_select_db($database,$db);
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8", $db); 
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $db);
mysql_query("SET character_set_client=utf8", $db);
mysql_query("SET character_set_connection=utf8", $db);
mysql_query("SET character_set_results=utf8", $db);
mb_language('uni');
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');


$code=$_GET['code'];
$ipAddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$fecha=date("Y-m-d");
$hora=date("H:i:s");
if($code!=0){
//This will insert a row each time the email is opened
$inserTrack=mysql_query("INSERT INTO emailTrack (idEmailTrack, track_code, ip, fecha, hora) VALUES ('', '$code', '$ipAddress', '$fecha', '$hora')", $db);
}


echo "<img src='https://syste-mart.com/images/mail.png' width='30' height='30'>";

?>
```

The error I get in gmail is:
The requested URL /proxy/SZKsK8dZS1ZgM4QsOMe78tbq5Pz-2eT5G7rdKoBw6onZwoDU0hOZ4J2qxO06uuEAjh479rICREC3e2PZkbx9yLEAq4RosKVG255lDwkcLYwRgrArBkCJeW1YLYja-v8DKtHoRfh2o1S7TG01eSbhdDEocSDGRSn11SA75z2WzOdMl7XYDB_p3Mywx1xNjzc_4kugvMgKu3-AR9wVRgryZ3Yo4cYanTzENcjf=s0-d-e1-ft was not found on this server

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: You are open to SQL injections. Don't use `mysql_` anymore. How does the first chunk of code relate? I would just have a `datetime` column. I also don't see any `/proxy/` in either code blocks.

Comment: So, the URL for the pixel, when Google parses it in the email must be resulting in a 404? This might be an issue of surviving transport. Are some of your random strings needing to be encoded differently?

Comment: Would like to see the raw email message.

Comment: The img code is part of the HTML email sent, all the code is working fine in other email providers except Gmail that seems to block outside content (the tracker)

Comment: They cache the image and load it off their own proxy. Doesn't explain the 404. Was their nothing else on the end of the URI you shared... `d-e1-ft#originalurl.com?foo`

Comment: Hmm. Maybe they did change practices... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20379732/gmail-blocking-pixel-tracking-1x1-pixel-since-today-morning They want you to drink their cool-aid... https://htmlemail.io/blog/google-analytics-email-tracking

Comment: The complete erro of showing the image is 404. That’s an error.

The requested URL /proxy/23LfiZIiQPdNE7G4lZN978HxPexI-VCSCHm3OYO4AKsz-jx3C85r60DzU2xu3VlM2I3yAx-H253SLIg3tWl_3DUvSpKJX1GdNROYKy3gDte4l0LTi5aGDCr2_RjW4K8mlagaanJnfYAc-zaG1GSbzVD5eA2qY6RL8WL96BgZV-PqM2_TadQ9odPEy7yNwOfpdRv3CBboPq4X2GeVmZelREbHIpnoH22LYRXq=s0-d-e1-ft was not found on this server. That’s all we know.