# Pixel Email Tracking not working for Gmail

Tags: php, html, image, email, http-headers

I am using a 10 x 10 pixel for email opening tracking, which works fine for every mail provider but Gmail.

Here are my Headers:

```
header("Content-Type: image/png");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Content-Length: 0");
```

Comment: Why would the headers be relevant, when Gmail likely blocks all remote images per default?

Comment: Headers were basically recommended by everyone as the Gmail Image Caching prevents the Email Tracking

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20379732/9613905